# What is a lukewarm black hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature, definition, hawking-radiation

What is a [lukewarm black hole](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=lukewarm+black+hole)?
They supposedly have something to do with hawking radiation.

I would like an explanation of their properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In black hole physics the term “lukewarm black hole” refers to asymptotically de Sitter black hole solutions that have equal temperatures of the black hole and cosmological horizons ($T_b = T_c$) (generally, the temperatures are different).

For example, for solutions from Reissner–Nordström–de Sitter family the black hole would be lukewarm when its mass and charge have the same absolute value, $|Q|=M$ (in geometric units). These solutions are generalization of extreme (asymptotically flat) Reissner–Nordström solution to a positive cosmological constant. See e.g. [Romans, 1991](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9203018) or [Cai et al., 1997](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9708062) for details. One can also find lukewarm solutions in other black hole families (such as Kerr–de Sitter).